# Do I need external pull up resistors for TX and RX lines in CP2102N?

Tags: pcb-design, uart, cp2102

I want to use it to program a microcontroller and this is the recommended set up from the data sheet. I was wonder If I need these resistors or not. [image: Recommended UART programming set up]

I am not asking if STM32 chips require pull ups. I know they are required I am asking whether they are built in Silicon Labs CP2102N or not.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pull up resistors on UART](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/270834/pull-up-resistors-on-uart)

Comment: read the CP2102N datasheet

Comment: @jsotola Would you elaborate. I read the datasheet and I could not find the answer. May be there is something that is understood by default and I did not understand it.

Comment: Unless enabled in ST uC, if not possible. add them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked the same question in Silicon Labs community website and they answered politely that CP2102N does have built-in pull up resistors. I tested this yesterday and I managed to program my microcontroller.